# How can you optimize this code in my trigger? SOQL Limit

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger, email2case

The problem that exists in production is caused by the use of the email to case tool. The case object has two lookup fields, one for account and the other for contact. When creating the case, the system automatically matches in the event that the sender of the incoming email matches the email of the associate's personal account, and in that case performs account assignment and contact on the case.
It is important to note that associates use person account in Salesforce, and that we only use the account object for all our processes.
According to the Email to Case configuration, the entry of mail to a routing box configured to generate email cases generates a "Case to Type" record type case. At that moment, if a match is found with the email, paste the same personal account of the associate to the field "Account Name" and "Contact Name".
When the case is received, the agent (user) that manages the case performs a verification with the associate's data and typifies the case (makes a RecordType change). If it does not apply, they change the associate (change the "Account Name" field) but do not change the "Contact Name" because it is not a field that is used (it is not taken into account). This is where the problem occurs, because the case is assigned to the respective associate's account, but continues to be linked to the original associate's personal account by the "Contact Name" lookup field.
Beyond this untidiness, in the "Cases" Quick Links related list that appears in the associate's 360 view, both the cases that have the "Associate Name" field linked to that associate, as well as those that are listed as "Name of the Contact" in another case whose field has not been changed, as mentioned in the previous paragraph.

To solve this requirement I wrote a method that sets the Contact Name field = null

```
public static void actualizarCuentaConContacto(List<case> cases){
    for (Case caso : cases) {
        caso.ContactId = null;
    }
}
```

I share the trigger code here:

```
public with sharing class CaseTriggerHandler extends TriggerHandler {
List<Case> lNew = (List<Case>) Trigger.new;
List<Case> lOld = (List<Case>) Trigger.old;
Map<Id,Case> mNew = (Map<Id,Case>) Trigger.newMap;
Map<Id,Case> mOld = (Map<Id,Case>) Trigger.oldMap;



public override void beforeUpdate() {
    

List<Case> casesToUpdateContact = new List<Case>();
    Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
    Set<Id> oldAccountIds = new Set<Id>();
    for (Case casos : lNew) {
        accountIds.add(casos.AccountId);
    }
    for (Case oldCase : lOld) {
        oldAccountIds.add(oldCase.AccountId);
    }
    Map<Id, Account> accountMap = new Map<Id,Account>([
        SELECT isPersonAccount
        FROM Account
        WHERE Id IN :accountIds
    ]);
    Map<Id, Boolean> isPersonAccountByCaseId = new Map<Id, Boolean>();
    for (Case casos : lNew) {
        if (accountMap.containsKey(casos.AccountId)) {
            isPersonAccountByCaseId.put(casos.Id, accountMap.get(casos.AccountId).isPersonAccount);
        }
    }
    Map<Id,Account> oldAccountsMap = new Map<Id,Account>([
        SELECT isPersonAccount
        FROM Account
        WHERE Id IN :oldAccountIds
    ]);
    Map<Id, Boolean> isOldPersonAccountByCaseId = new Map<Id, Boolean>();
    for (Case casos : lOld) {
        if (oldAccountsMap.containsKey(casos.AccountId)) {
            isOldPersonAccountByCaseId.put(casos.Id, oldAccountsMap.get(casos.AccountId).isPersonAccount);
        }
    }
    for(Case caso : lNew) {
        Case oldCase = mOld.get(caso.Id);
        Boolean rtToValidateResp = caso.RecordTypeId == seguimientoRtId
                                    || caso.RecordTypeId == internacionRtId
                                    || caso.RecordTypeId == reintegroRtId
                                    || caso.RecordTypeId == apRtId;
        Boolean isFromEM = String.isNotBlank(caso.Evento_Medico__c)
                            && (caso.RecordTypeId == seguimientoRtId
                                || caso.RecordTypeId == internacionRtId);
        if(oldCase.RecordTypeId == casoATipificarRtId && oldCase.RecordTypeId != caso.RecordTypeId){
            caso.Cambio_Manual__c = false;
            caso.Usuario__c = null;
            if(caso.Type == null){
                Case dummyCase = (Case)Case.sObjectType.newSObject(caso.RecordTypeId,true);
                caso.Type = dummyCase.Type;
            }
            casesToChangeDelegacion.add(caso);
            if(casosValidosActualizarStatus.contains(caso.RecordTypeId)){
                casesToUpdateStatus.add(caso);
            }else if(caso.RecordTypeId == solicitudDeDatosParticulares){
                caso.SuppliedEmail = '';
            }
            if (caso.AccountId != oldCase.AccountId && (isPersonAccountByCaseId.get(caso.Id) || isOldPersonAccountByCaseId.get(caso.Id))) {
                casesToUpdateContact.add(caso);
            }
        }
```

The trigger runs correctly and meets the requirement, the problem arises when trying to pass it to UAT gives me an error due to SOQL limits.
I would be needing to optimize my code, I would appreciate it if you could help me. Regards

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include code _as text_, not a screenshot.

Comment: Ready, I fixed it and put it in code

Comment: What error are you facing ? can you put the error message ?

Comment: LIMIT_EXCEEDED: System.LimitException: Too many SOQL queries: 101. Stack Trace: Class.CasoDocumentacionFinalizadaBtnCtrl.updateReintegro: line 156, column 1 Class.CasoDocumentacionFinalizadaBtnCtrl.ChangeStatusToReintegro: line 38, column 1 Class.CasoDocumentacionFinalizadaBtnCtrlTest.whenTheResponseIsCorrect_updateTheReintegroPrestacionesAndAlerts: line 159, column 1

Comment: Likely your problem lies outside of the code you have posted in other code that responds to the blanking of the `ContactId`. Looking in the debug logs may give you an idea of what other code runs in that case.

Comment: it doesn't look like you posted the entire triggerHandler

Answer (score 0):

You could have a recursive trigger due to code outside of what you are showing here.  Do you have a setMaxLoopCount method in your Trigger Handler class to prevent recursion?

There is an example in this trigger-framework:
https://github.com/kevinohara80/sfdc-trigger-framework